# Using Testcontainers at Development Time doesnt support DynamicPropertyRegistry

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

Using Testcontainers at Development Time I have

```
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ContainersConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakContainer keycloakContainer(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        KeycloakContainer keycloakContainer = new KeycloakContainer()...
        keycloakContainer.start();

        registry.add("keycloak.server.external-url", () -> keycloakContainer.getAuthServerUrl());
        registry.add("keycloak.server.internal-url", () -> keycloakContainer.getAuthServerUrl());
        registry.add("keycloak.dev-portal-realm", () -> "master");

        return keycloakContainer;
    }
}
```

with

```java
public class DMATestApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.from(DeveloperManagerApplication::main).with(ContainersConfiguration.class).run(args);;
        }
```

---

Upon running
`gradle bootTestRun` it throws
`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry' available:`

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1383)
```

While reading the docs it suggests it is possible, when @ServiceConnection isn't supported

```
Using a @ServiceConnection is recommended whenever possible, however, dynamic properties can be a useful fallback for technologies that don’t yet have @ServiceConnection support.
```

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.testcontainers.at-development-time

Does anyone know if dynamic properties are supported?

Comment: Do you have the `spring-boot-testcontainers` dependency added as a dependency? Else the needed auto configuration classes aren't present. That being said could you provide a sample that reproduces this and please add your build file as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have found the issue

It is due to the project using spring cloud kubernetes

`implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'  `

The introduction of the bootstrap for some reason prevents TestcontainersPropertySourceAutoConfiguration from kicking in.